# Problem with upload image to google drive using php

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

On my site I use google api to upload images in folder. Actually, there is no official documentation from google how to use api using php, only python, js and etc. Current problem is that I get no errors, but file isn't uploading. I'm 100% sure that my service workers work (sorry for such bad english) properly. Below I put my php code for uploading images:

```
<?php
include '../vendor/autoload.php';

function handleGoogleDrive($file)
{
    //connecting to google drive
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Somesite');
    $client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE]);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setAuthConfig('./credentials.json');
    $client->setClientId('2445617429-6k99ikago0s0jdh5q5k3o37de6lqtsd3.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('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');
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    //counting amount of files in folder, there is no real reason in doing that
    //it is just a test of connecting
    $folder_id = '1eQtNOJjlA2CalZYb90bEs34IaP6v9ZHM';
    $options = [
        'q' => "'" . $folder_id . "' in parents",
        'fields' => 'files(id, name)'
    ];
    //printing result
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($options);
    echo count($results->getFiles());
    //trying to add file
    $data = file_get_contents("../test.jpg");
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName(uniqid(). '.jpg');
    $file->setDescription('A test document');
    $file->setMimeType('image/jpeg');
    $new_file = $service->files->create($file, [
        'data' => $data,
        'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    ]);
    print_r($new_file);
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `but nothing actually changes`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: @Tanaike, I meant that file still wasn't uploaded to the Google drive

Comment: @Tanaike, also I print my new file variable, and everything is looking great, but Google Drive is still empty

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that `'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',` is not required to be included. But, I think that your script can upload a file to Google Drive. So, I cannot understand `but Google Drive is still empty`. I apologize for this. For example, when you change the sample file, will the situation be changed?

Comment: Can you do a file.list and check again that a new file was not created?

Comment: @DalmTo after I watch If there some new files, I got only file I'have alredy had

Comment: @Tanakie, I don't really know how to change files on google drive, but I think I have problems with service accounts, Oauth and things like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my standard upload code for uploading.

Try removing `'uploadType' => 'multipart',` in your code.

I also cant see you setting the folder id when you upload your file which means its going to root directory.

```
// Upload a file to the users Google Drive account
try{
    $filePath = "image.png";
    $folder_id = '1eQtNOJjlA2CalZYb90bEs34IaP6v9ZHM';
    $fileMetadata = new Drive\DriveFile();
    $fileMetadata->setName("image.png");
    $fileMetadata->setMimeType('image/png');
    $fileMetadata->setParents(array($folder_id));

    $content = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $mimeType=mime_content_type($filePath);

    $request  = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
        'data' => $content,
        'mimeType' => $mimeType,
        'fields' => 'id'));

    printf("File ID: %s\n", $request->id);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Remember if you are using a service account, files are uploaded to the service accounts drive account unless you add the folder you want to upload the file to.

## files list

```
// Print the next 10 events on the user's drive account.
try{


    $optParams = array(
        'pageSize' => 10,
        'fields' => 'files(id,name,mimeType)'
    );
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
    $files = $results->getFiles();

    if (empty($files)) {
        print "No files found.\n";
    } else {
        print "Files:\n";
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $id = $file->id;

            printf("%s - (%s) - (%s)\n", $file->getId(), $file->getName(), $file->getMimeType());
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, code is great, only problem is that I get insufficientParentPermissions error

Comment: Assuming the directory you are uploading to, is not on the service accounts drive account. Did you grant the service account access to it?  Does it have write access?

Comment: @DalmTo, yes I open access everybody who have a link, and additionaly give access to service account, probably it hasn't some write acsess

Comment: The share with me link is not the same as granting someone access.   You need to go to the google drive web app click share and take the service account email address and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code which was suggested to me, this is full solution.
(Thanks everybody who helped me)

```
<?php
include '../vendor/autoload.php';
function handleGoogleDrive($file)
{
    //connecting to google drive
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('YOUR ID IN SECRET FILE');
    $client->setClientSecret(YOUR SECRET IN JSON FILE);
    $client->setRedirectUri(YOUR REDIRECT URI);
    //you should register redirect uri
    $client->setApplicationName('Somesite');
    $client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE]);
    $client->setAuthConfig('./credentials.json');
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    try{
        $filePath = "../test.jpg";
        $folder_id = 'YOUR FOLDER ID';
        $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $fileMetadata->setName("image.png");
        $fileMetadata->setMimeType('image/png');
        $fileMetadata->setParents(array($folder_id));
    
        $content = file_get_contents($filePath);
        $mimeType=mime_content_type($filePath);
    
        $request  = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
            'data' => $content,
            'mimeType' => $mimeType,
            'fields' => 'id'));
    
        printf("File ID: %s\n", $request->id);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
    }
    try{


        $optParams = array(
            'pageSize' => 10,
            'fields' => 'files(id,name,mimeType)'
        );
        $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
        $files = $results->getFiles();
    
        if (empty($files)) {
            print "No files found.\n";
        } else {
            print "Files:\n";
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $id = $file->id;
    
                printf("%s - (%s) - (%s)\n", $file->getId(), $file->getName(), $file->getMimeType());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
        echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```